# iOS interactivePopGestureRecognizer enables itself after ViewController is pushed

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios8, interactivepopgesture

I have a subclass of *UINavigationController* that has maximum of 4 *ViewControllers* in the stack. Lets call them firstVC ... fourthVC. My NavController can perform custom transitions between VCs and ios7/8 back gesture is supposed to be disabled and enabled depending on which VC is currently at the top of the stack. I've set my root VC (firstVC) as a NavController's *delegate* and trying to enable/disable back gesture in the delegate's method

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {

    if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(needsBackGestureEnabled)]) {

        [self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer setEnabled:YES];
        NSLog(@"Back gesture enabled");
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = (id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)self;

    } else {

        if ([navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer isEnabled]) {
            [self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer setEnabled:NO];
            NSLog(@"Back gesture disabled");
            self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;
        }
    }

}
```

It works like a charm except one glitch. I feel like a short scheme might explain situation better:

FirstVC -[CustomTran]-> SecondVC -[push]-> ThirdVC -[push]-> FourthVC

FourthVC is the only one that have *-needsBackGestureEnabled* selector, but after transition from second to third back gesture gets enabled by itself. Even though the back button is susbtituted with the CustomBarButtonItem. I feel like performing default *-pushViewController* animation makes back gesture enabled somehow. I tried to ecplicitly disable it in my NavController subclass in *-pushViewController* but it didn't change a thing. Any idea why this is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through this code during the appropriate transition? What happens?

Comment: When you say appropriate transition you mean the one in question above? SecondVC -[push]-> ThirdVC? I tried, it skips both conditions as it should. Neither back gesture is supposed to be enabled nor needs to be enabled here. After this method it goes into some deep "animation completed" blocks and callbacks, sadly I don't know this stuff well enough to get deeper. Thanks for correcting the post by the way.